# Deploying a Laravel project with docker gives a user permission error

Tags: php, laravel, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I have a docker compose and Dockerfile, when building the project builds and the containers run but gives the site gives the error:

**The stream or file "/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode**

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    mysql-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    nano \
    curl \
    libzip-dev

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

COPY . /var/www/

COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

USER www

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: You're first copying the entire sourcecode into the docker container, then giving permissions (chown) and then binding a volume to it. What I would do is not copy the sourcecode to the container, it's not necessary, *unless* you're using a Mac. In that case: don't bind the volume in your docker-compose.yml file

Comment: Is there a file `./storage/logs/laravel.log` existed and it can not be accessed by laravel user? Can you `ls -l ./storage/logs/` from the directory of the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: This is the result: -rw-r--r-- 1 root www-data 37641 Jan  1 07:58 laravel.log

Answer (score 0):

"docker-compose exec app chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www"
solved my problem